# how to print out only commit author and commit date by using git log?

Tags: linux, git, git-log

I want to list all commit by using git log, in which each line contain [commit author]: commit date

For example:

```
[name]: 7 February 2021
```

Answer (score 6):

the `git help log` documentation has a rather interesting section titled `PRETTY FORMATS` that you will have to read for more details.

In short,

```
git log '--pretty=[%aN]: %aD'
```

is probably close to what you want. Note that I chose the "author date" as the commit date, because I don't know exactly what data you're interested in! If you need another date, e.g. commit/merge dates, then you'll have to refer to the documentation to pick the right format string yourself. You can specify the date format for most date fields using the `--date=<format>` option, which is also documented there.